# How to show chid div hover on parent class Via CSS

Tags: css

CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .coverhover {
        background: url("images/chover.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
        height: 249px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        position: absolute;   // if i remove position property that time hover work 
        width: 668px;}
        a.preview_image:hover .coverhover{
            display:block
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
    <a class="preview_image" href="http://localhost/bestfunnytime/crime-scene-donot-cross/">
        <span class="coverhover"></span>
        <img class="attachment-full wp-post-image" width="850" height="315" alt="Crime-Scene-Do-Not-Cross" src="http://localhost/bestfunnytime/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Crime-Scene-Do-Not-Cross.jpg" draggable="false">
    </a>
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Your `<span class="coverhover" />` element doesn't have any contents to show. Add some content.

Comment: @RahilWazir u r right my code is working fine on that url thecodedeveloper.com/om but not working same code here bestfunnytime.com

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
.preview_image:hover > .attachment-full {
  display: block;
}
```

For your code:

```
a.preview_image:hover > .coverhover{
  display: block;
}
```

Oops, while providing the answer for your code, I almost forgot that the element you're trying to show has no content, so even if it has a `display: block` it would still be as that it is hidden. So try to add some content to it.

`>` selector selects all the child elements (the elements on the right side) where the parent element is the element to the right of this selector.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html Read the list of the CSS selectors.

More reference at css-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

And then finally Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Good luck!

Comment: @vikastyagi I have updated my answer :) and I have included some more reference links to the post too..You can get the help from these posts too..:) And yes, I have used your code and updated it..:) It fits for your situation too now..:)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan OP code is working fine. He doesn't have to use direct descendant `>` selector at all.

Comment: @RahilWazir, whoops I almost forgot that..hehe I was considering the `img` as the element to be shown..